# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.URI cannot be cast to java.net.URL

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception

I am writing a URL validator. The code is as follows

```
public ValidationResult validate(final Object data, final Object root, final String path, final ValidationContext validationContext, final EvaluationContext evaluationContext) {

    ValidationResult validationResult = new ValidationResult();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<URL> URLs = (List<URL>)data;

    UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();
    boolean isValid = true;
    for (URL websiteURL : URLs) {

        if (urlValidator.isValid(websiteURL.getPath())) {
            isValid = true;
        } else {
            isValid = false;
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("websiteURL.getPath() " + websiteURL.getPath());         
    }
    System.out.println("websiteURL.getPath() " + isValid);  

    return validationResult;
}
```

While debugging i found that `for (URL websiteURL : URLs)` is giving `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.URI cannot be cast to java.net.URL` error. How can i make my logic work?

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is here:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<URL> URLs = (List<URL>)data;
```

In fact, it would appear that you are calling this code with an object that is a list of `URI` objects rather than a list of `URL` objects.  At any rate, the class cast is happening in a hidden cast that happens when the object returned by the `Iterator.next()` object is assigned to `websiteURL`.

It is not really clear what the correct solution to this is:

- You could (possibly) change the code that calls this to pass it a list containing `URL` objects ... as expected by the validator.
- You could change the validator to work on a list of `URI` objects ... starting with the declaration of the `URLs` variable. (YUCK!  Didn't anyone explain Java identifier conventions to you??)

  ```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<URI> uris = (List<URI>)data;
  ```
- You could change the validator to work with `URL` and `URI` objects ... starting by changing the above declaration to:

  ```
    List<?> urls = (List) data;
  ```

  Then you need to use `instanceof` to discriminate between `URI` and `URL` objects before validating them.

For the record, the way to convert a `URI` to a `URL` is to call `URI.toURL()` on it.

Comment: why is it casting it to URI when i am giving URL in the list type ?  How can i coerce it to be URL object.

Comment: 1)  It is not being cast to `URI`.  It is being cast to `URL`. And the cast is happening >>because<< you declared the list type as `List<URL>`.   2) See the last sentence of my Answer.  However, you must get of the unchecked cast of the `data` to `List<URL>` because that is problematic.